# Documentation of lilypond's scheme classes (Pitch, Score etc.)

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

Where are lilypond's scheme classes (Pitch, Score etc.) documented?

For example the documentation of the scheme-function [ly:pitch?](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/internals/scheme-functions#index-ly_003apitch_003f) says *"Is x a smob of class Pitch?"*.

But there is no link or reference to where the class Pitch is documented.

There is also lilypond's github repository where one can search for the header files, e.g. for [pich.hh](https://github.com/lilypond/lilypond/blob/master/lily/include/pitch.hh) to see how this class is implemented.

But... is there some kind of documentation for all the classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Lilypond is an open source project, so people will only create documentation if they feel it is necessary. But there is a good technical guide written by Jean Abou-Samra (one of the core devs):

https://extending-lilypond.gitlab.io/

For more detailed questions consider joining the Lilypond mailing lists.

Comment: Oh, terrific! I remember another user starting a website like this several years ago, but I haven't checked in a while. I'm excited to dig into this.

Comment: Might have been https://scheme-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra Please help clarifying the differences between "Extending LilyPond" and "Scheme (in LilyPond)". I've posted [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/131834/94106)